# .htaccess 301 redirect to a new URL structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have the following URL structure that I need 301'd to a new URL structure.

OLD STRUCTURE
 /bla-bla-bla-400252596261.html

NEW STRUCTURE
 /listing/bla-bla-bla-400252596261.html

How can I accomplish this in .htacces?

EDIT: I do have other files on the root, but not ending in .html so it should match against that string. So any file in the root matching a .html extension should be redirected to /listing/bla-bla-bla-400252596261.html page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/listing.*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /listing/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

More examples [here](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml)

Comment: It's strange, 'cause it works for me. I'm using Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 However sometimes my Chrome caches old responses (in the same time FF works correctly)

Comment: I am getting this in the URL which appears to be a redirect loop.

http://www.antique-furniture-online.com/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/listing/index.php/view/antique-primitive-medicine-cabinet-very-unique-320858829283.html

Comment: I don't see there my conditions & rule. Can you show me final version of .htaccess? And give me please 2 urls: first one is what you enter and second one is where user must be redirected.